# Remaining circuit 220Vac

Tags: switching

I am newbie, I am looking for a circuit that remaining power for about 5 minutes after switch off the main switch of a 25W fan at 220Vac. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @winny, s/he's looking for a bathroom fan timer to keep the fan running after the light is switched off. Just buy one

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard bathroom fan timer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9Eje9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A fan delay-off timer.*

- An "always-on" live feed is required for the timer.
- Switching on SW1 lights the light and feeds the timer.
- Switching off SW1 turns off the light and starts the off-delay timer.
- The fan runs while the light is on and remains running for a set time after SW1 is switched off.